# specific route in column in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

here I want to show this column ( show and share  ) if only the status is approval witch I stored the approval status in my table as number (2).
then I the status is approval the student allows access to show.blade.php in request folder ..this is the path I want to route the approval student to it
( ApprovalStudent\Request\show )

```html
@foreach($students as $student)
<tr>
    <th scope="col"><a href="ApprovalStudent\Request\show"> show and share </a></th>
    <th scope="col">{{$student->status->name}}</th>
    <th scope="col">{{$student->type->name}}</th>
    <th scope="col">{{$student->uniid}}</th>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

how can I write this? same I want

Comment: Couldn't you just use `if` statement?

Comment: What is the approval status number name? is it `$student->status->number`?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just use an `if` statement.

```
@if($student->status->name == 'approval')
    <th scope="col"><a href="ApprovalStudent\Request\show"> show and share </a></th>
@endif
```

Comment: dose not running

Comment: don't show the column even the status is approval... I store the approval as integer =  2

Comment: @shrooq `status->name` is an integer? If so, just change `'approval'` in the code above to `2`.

Comment: I write it  but it doesn't work yet @if($student->status->name == '2')
    <th scope="col"><a href="ApprovalStudent\Request\show"> show and share </a></th>
@endif

Comment: @shrooq is there a student with this status? Have you tried dumpimg `$student->status->name`? There are a lot of things that can be causing this problem. But I guarantee you that if everything is right, this simple `if` statement will work.